# How to escape a string variable in sed?

Tags: sed

Replace `/tmp/storequote` with `/tmp/tmpdata` in sed:

```
sudo sed -i "s/\/tmp\/storequote/\/tmp\/tmpdata/g" config.py
```

It works fine,`/` was escaped by `\`.I want to use string variable which contains special characters in sed.

```
string1='/tmp/tmpdata'
string2='/tmp/storequote'
sudo sed -i "s/$string1/$string2/g"  config.py
```

It encounter a issue:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown option to `s'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The simple and common fix is to use an alternative separator for the `s` command, for example `s|$string1|$string2|g`. That said, I'd suggest to be very cafeful when you play with dynamic sed expressions as it is not only error-prone but unsafe if the shell variables are not strictly validated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed allows you to use other separators than `/` in a substitution.

For example, with a colon:

```
sudo sed -i "s:$string1:$string2:g"  config.py
```

Now suppose `string1` (or `string2`) contains a colon, you'll again get a broken sed command. Same if they contain a semi-colon, which is used to separate `sed` commands.

If you use bash, one solution to easily escape those special characters is to carefully choose a separator that has a special meaning for bash (like `|`), and use `printf %q` which will escape it for you, while keeping your command readable:

```
printf -v sed_command 's|%q|%q|g' "$string1" "$string2"
sudo sed -i "$sed_command" config.py
```

Warning: this hack won't escape dot characters in `string1` which will retain their special meaning (i.e. any character). Keep in mind this is a hack that saves you from having headaches escaping possible special char.